# Add and Custom category for posts "PAGE"

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field, pages, categories

I want to create custom category page  for posts "PAGE" for an internal use.

The categories will be the list of the clients

1. I want to remove somes fields (like slug, description, parent category 
   and also the grey texte)
2. Remove columns (description, count, slug)
3. Add custom field (client logo, market segment, free comment)
4. Make all fields required to add client (except free comment)
5. assigned a page to a unique category "Client"

Thats what I have :

[image]

That's what I'm looking for :

[image]

My approche :

I begin by adding the code on function.php to create categories

```
 function add_taxonomies_to_pages() {

      register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'page' );
  } 

 add_action( 'init', 'add_taxonomies_to_pages' );


 if ( ! is_admin() ) {
 add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'category_archives' );

   }

// Add Page as a post_type in the archive.php 

function category_archives( $wp_query ) {

    $my_post_array = array('post','page');

    if ( $wp_query->get( 'category_name' ) || $wp_query->get( 'cat' ) )
      $wp_query->set( 'post_type', $my_post_array );


  }

?>
```

I try tu use PODS to create fields  (logo client, market segment and free comment) and add requirement for all the fields except free comment. But the problem is when I create client is just need Name of the category "client" and created it (don't take on consideration the others fields).

Thanks in advance for your support.

UPDATE :

With CPT and ACF i created a new taxonomy named Customers with new fields (client name, client Logo,   market segment, free comment)

Like you see in the picture below :

[image]

Now, i'm looking for disable or remove the fields in red and also the columns (name, description, slug, count) and replace them by (client name, market segment)

Comment: So, why don't you use a custom post type? in yout case it makes much more sense and it's a lot less work, and for the fields you can create them yourself and make them required with js, or you can use the `Advanced Custom Fields` plugin

Comment: Thanks. I used ACF with CPT it's works but still have some issues. I want to definitely  disable somes fields like you see in the picture. (Parent category, slug, description) I want also to remove columns ( description, slug and count). have you an idea?